# Are past irrelevant job experiences relevant to add in your resume as a software engineer?

Tags: resume, career-development, work-experience, career-switch

I'm a software developer who has worked professionally for 3 years. Prior to becoming a software engineer, I was working in the banking sector as a banker my work revolved handling customers and doing back office accounting. At some point in my life I realized that my real passion was in technology so embarked in acquiring full stack web development skills from some coding bootcamp. For me, it was an easy transition because I had previous knowledge in IT and programming in general with a degree in BMIT I did years back before becoming a banker. I have worked for a couple of tech companies and currently I'm employed fulltime.

Should I add my previous banking work experiences in resume? I realized that if I leave out the banking experience from the resume obviously the person who see's the resume will notice gaps and that doesn't look good.

Comment: Yes, this was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the bottom line is: you only add the relevant information in a CV.

To elaborate: **Describe** the past experiences which are relevant to the job profile you're applying for, and just **mention** the work tenure of other jobs you held. The jobs which are not directly relevant, can be just a one-liner(s), and if applicable, can mention the learnings you obtained from those jobs which can help you in your current / future assignments. No further elaboration is needed.

Just because one held multiple jobs, the CV does not need detailing unless the role/position being applied for is relevant with the experience gained from those engagements.

Comment: I can't stress this enough. Foucusing on what is relevant is good both for the CV writer and the recruiter.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I add my previous banking work experiences in resume?

## Yes

Obviously, for each section of experience, you have to decide how detailed it needs to be. Your last technical job might be very detailed, while your banking job might just be a one-liner with the job title and company at the end of the list.

But if it is an important part of your work life (not just a two month temp job to pay the rent in between other long term jobs) then list it. To make sure you don't have gaps, but also because experience is experience and you will never know when it comes in handy.

Your experience might be useful. You might be more qualified to write software for banks than the next guy who did pool supply sales. But your employer will never know if you don't put it there, even if it's just a one-liner hint.

Answer (score 2):

I think it really depends. If your resume is targeting a technical job, then you prioritise any technical experience you've had.

Non relevant experience should stay on your resume until you have enough experience in your chosen industry that there is no longer room for it.

*If choosing between you and a candidate with exactly the same (relevant) experience, your (irrelevant) experience now becomes a deciding factor. - Any good employer would see transferrable skills not irrelevance.*

One way to avoid gaps in your resume is to just list the number of years at each job, not the specific years.