# Projects on resume

Tags: resume, projects, backend

can I add projects that are not related to my specialization(backend web developer) to my resume. Ex: Algorithm Visualization, Chess Solver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are past irrelevant job experiences relevant to add in your resume as a software engineer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166414/are-past-irrelevant-job-experiences-relevant-to-add-in-your-resume-as-a-software)

Comment: I don't see why projects that showcase your programming abilities would not be relevant. But as a general rule: most relevant projects first and if you have enough of those anyways just drop the rest.

Answer (score 4):

*Can* you? Certainly.

*Should* you? That depends. When you think that these projects demonstrate skills and experience which are relevant for the position you apply to, then yes. Unless of course you already have so much on your resume that it looks like padding.

How much is too much and looks like padding? That depends on the personal opinions of the person reading your resume.